# Better alternatives to the Lambert BRDF

Tags: brdf, physically-based, diffuse

After reading about the new [Disney Diffuse BRDF](https://disney-animation.s3.amazonaws.com/library/s2012_pbs_disney_brdf_notes_v2.pdf), I have been wondering if this is currently the best Diffuse BRDF at the moment? How much more of a difference would this make compared to using a Lambertian BRDF? I have heard of other BRDFs such as Hanrahan-Krueger and Oren-Nayar, are these also better?

[image]

Comment: Cook-torrance is popular these days, it takes micro geometry into account so attenuates differently to lambert.

Comment: Disney's BRDF is pretty much the top of the line as far as diffuse BRDFs go, yes.